# Is it possible to view LRU-K values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server's `sys.dm_os_memory_cache_entries`, it is possible to view both the original cost of an entry in the cache as well as the current cost of the cache entry (`original_cost` and `current_cost` respectively). The DMV `sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors` contains a record of the pages that are currently in memory as well as some metadata about the pages. One interesting chunk of info not available in the DVM are the LRU-K values for the data pages.

Is it possible to get the LRU-K values for data pages in buffer pool in SQL Server? If so, how?

Comment: Is this version-specific?

Comment: @JNK - In a perfect world, no, but as long as it works on SQL Server 2012 I don't really worry.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is in fact no useful way to do this as far as I can see.

The other answer mentions `DBCC PAGE` and leaves it up to the reader to figure out the details. From experimentation I assume they mean `bUse1`.

This fails to take account that `DBCC PAGE` is itself a use of the page and the value gets updated **before** it is shown to us.

A script demonstrating this is below (takes 12 seconds to run).

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE T(X INT);

INSERT INTO T VALUES(1);

DECLARE @DBCCPAGE NVARCHAR(100);

SELECT @DBCCPAGE = 'DBCC PAGE(0,' + CAST(file_id AS VARCHAR) + ',' + CAST(page_id AS VARCHAR) + ',0) WITH TABLERESULTS;'
FROM   T CROSS APPLY  sys.fn_PhysLocCracker (%%physloc%%)

DECLARE @DbccResults TABLE 
(
      ID INT IDENTITY,
      ParentObject VARCHAR(1000)NULL,
      Object VARCHAR(4000)NULL,
      Field VARCHAR(1000)NULL,
      ObjectValue VARCHAR(MAX)NULL
)    
INSERT INTO @DbccResults EXEC(@DBCCPAGE)  
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:07'
INSERT INTO @DbccResults EXEC(@DBCCPAGE)  
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
INSERT INTO @DbccResults EXEC(@DBCCPAGE)             

SELECT *
FROM @DbccResults   
WHERE Field = 'bUse1'    
ORDER BY ID

EXEC(@DBCCPAGE) 

DROP TABLE T
```

Typical results are

```
+----+--------------+-------------------------+-------+-------------+
| ID | ParentObject |         Object          | Field | ObjectValue |
+----+--------------+-------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  8 | BUFFER:      | BUF @0x00000002FE1F1440 | bUse1 |       54938 |
| 49 | BUFFER:      | BUF @0x00000002FE1F1440 | bUse1 |       54945 |
| 90 | BUFFER:      | BUF @0x00000002FE1F1440 | bUse1 |       54950 |
+----+--------------+-------------------------+-------+-------------+
```

With the second result being

```
+---------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------------+
| BUFFER: | BUF @0x00000002FE1F1440 | bpage        | 0x00000002F4968000 |
| BUFFER: | BUF @0x00000002FE1F1440 | bhash        | 0x0000000000000000 |
| BUFFER: | BUF @0x00000002FE1F1440 | bpageno      | (1:120)            |
| BUFFER: | BUF @0x00000002FE1F1440 | bdbid        | 8                  |
| BUFFER: | BUF @0x00000002FE1F1440 | breferences  | 0                  |
| BUFFER: | BUF @0x00000002FE1F1440 | bcputicks    | 0                  |
| BUFFER: | BUF @0x00000002FE1F1440 | bsampleCount | 0                  |
| BUFFER: | BUF @0x00000002FE1F1440 | bUse1        | 54950              |
| BUFFER: | BUF @0x00000002FE1F1440 | bstat        | 0x9                |
| BUFFER: | BUF @0x00000002FE1F1440 | blog         | 0x1c9a             |
| BUFFER: | BUF @0x00000002FE1F1440 | bnext        | 0x0000000000000000 |
+---------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

The output after the 7 second delay is incremented by 7 and after the 5 second delay by 5.

So it seems clear that these LRU values are seconds since some epoch. Restarting the SQL Server service does not alter the epoch but restarting the machine does.

The value rolls over every 65,536 seconds so I presume that it just uses something like `system_up_time mod 65536`

This does leave one unanswered questions in my mind (any takers?). SQL Server uses `LRU-K` with `K=2` according to the internals book. Shouldn't there be a `bUse2`? If so where is that?

There is one way of observing the `bUse1` value without changing it that I know of though and that is [demonstrated by Bob Ward](http://youtu.be/9n6FzIf5Hy4?t=22m36s) here.

Attach a debugger to the SQL Server process and display referenced memory for the memory address of the buffer structure (shown to be `0x00000002FE1F1440` above).

I did this immediately after running the script above and saw the following.

[image]

(From previous experimentation I'd found the highlighted bytes were the only ones that changed between runs so these are definitely the right ones).

One surprising aspect is that `SELECT CAST(0xc896 as int)` = `51350`.

This is exactly 3600 (one hour) less than reported by `DBCC PAGE`.

I believe this to be some attempt to disfavour pages being kept in cache by calling `DBCC PAGE` itself. For a "normal" page select this one hour adjustment does not occur. After running

```
SELECT *
FROM T

SELECT ((ms_ticks) % 65536000) / 1000 AS [Roughly Expected Value]
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info
```

The value shown in memory is as expected.

The `DBCC` command actually updates that value twice. Once at

```
sqlmin.dll!BPool::Touch()  + 0x3bfe bytes   
sqlmin.dll!BPool::Get()  + 0x12e bytes  
sqlmin.dll!LatchedBuf::ReadLatch()  + 0x14f bytes   
sqlmin.dll!UtilDbccDumpPage()  + 0x364 bytes    
sqlmin.dll!DbccPage()  + 0xfa bytes 
sqllang.dll!DbccCommand::Execute()  + 0x153 bytes
```

With the higher value then again at

```
sqlmin.dll!LatchedBuf::FreeAndUnlatch()  + 0x71 bytes   
sqlmin.dll!UtilDbccDumpPage()  + 0x545 bytes    
sqlmin.dll!DbccPage()  + 0xfa bytes 
sqllang.dll!DbccCommand::Execute()  + 0x153 bytes
```

With the lower one.

I'm not aware of any way to get buffer addresses for pages without using `DBCC BUFFER`/ `DBCC PAGE` any way though and using both of these changes the value we are trying to inspect!

Comment: I don't suppose anything has appeared in recent versions (2016/2017/2019) to find this out has it?

Comment: @MrPurpleStreak - I haven't heard of anything in that area and doubt there is much demand for exposing this publicly

Comment: Thanks. Shame - I have a suspicion that our instance could survive on a lot less memory as I think a lot of data gets paged in and then just sits there (page life expectancy just climbs and climbs for ages, then drops off a cliff momentarily when a huge index scan happens) But I don't know if any of the data sitting there is actually read.  Given the data is there I hoped it might be a column in dm_os_buffer_descriptors - but it's not.  Trying to spec new servers/cloud dbs and working out how much ram it needs (as it can be $$$)

Answer (score 8):

As I mentioned to Mr. Peschka on twitter, this information is kept on the BUF structure that holds the page in memory. DBCC PAGE gives you this information as part of its header.